# Trouble returning variable in python function

Tags: python, function, return

I'm simply trying to modify a string and return the modified string, however, I'm getting "None" returned when print the variable.

```
def AddToListTwo(self,IndexPosition):
    filename = RemoveLeadingNums(self, str(self.listbox1.get(IndexPosition))) #get the filename, remove the leading numbers if there are any
    print filename #this prints None
    List2Contents = self.listbox2.get(0, END)
    if(filename not in List2Contents): #make sure the file isn't already in list 2
        self.listbox2.insert(0, filename)

def RemoveLeadingNums(self, words):
    if(isinstance(words,str)):
        match = re.search(r'^[0-9]*[.]',words)
        if match: #if there is a match, remove it, send it through to make sure there aren't repeating numbers
            RemoveLeadingNums(self, re.sub(r'^[0-9]*[.]',"",str(words)).lstrip())
        else:
            print words #this prints the value correctly
            return words
    if(isinstance(words,list)):
        print "list"
```

**edit - multiple people have commented saying I'm not returning the value if there is match. I don't want to return it if there is. It could be repeating (ex: 1.2. itema). So, I wanted to essentially use recursion to remove it, and THEN return the value**

Comment: This code looks so redundant. Why is `RemoveLeadingNums` recursive to begin with?

Comment: recursion. The value could be "1.2.4. item" and I want to remove that entire set of values prior to item.

Comment: And to respond to your edit, if you don't want to return anything if there's a match, don't assign the result to `filename`. This code makes no sense.

Comment: Looking at your edit -- I'm not sure you understand what `re.sub` does -- or perhaps you don't understand the immutability of strings?  I'm not sure, but it seems to me that you're missing something here...

Comment: @NullUserException You're misunderstanding it because you didn't even bother reading the comments. I use recursion to check if there's a match. IF there is, remove the undesired values and send it back through to check for a match again.

Comment: When I say that "it makes no sense" I mean I don't understand what you're trying to do. You don't need recursion to remove "an entire set," you could write that whole method as: `def remove(self, word): return re.sub(r'^[0-9.]+', '', words.lstrip())`. You're using recursion wrong.

Comment: @NullUserException why do you even bother helping if you're just going to insult?

Comment: How am I "insulting" you? Your code makes little sense to begin with (it made even less sense with the edit), and I'm not the only one to point that out. Why don't you explain what you're trying to accomplish rather than try to get us to fix your broken code?

Comment: I already explained, in the big bold edit above that has been there since before you commented.

Comment: And I already explained that you're using recursion wrong. I know what you *think* you're trying to do, but it won't work (think harder about how the recursion will play out). Read: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple conditions where `RemoveLeadingNums` returns `None`.  e.g. if the `if match:` branch is taken.  Perhaps that should be:

```
if match: 
    return RemoveLeadingNums(...
```

You also return `None` if you have any datatype that isn't a string passed in.

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything in the case of a match. It should be:

```
return RemoveLeadingNums( ... )
```

Comment: I did. Now it makes even less sense. Without the return, that call to RemoveLeadingNums does *absolutely nothing*, because the string is not changed.

Comment: Yes it has. RemoveLeadingNums(self, re.sub(r'^[0-9]*[.]',"",str(words)).lstrip())

Comment: Let's add recursion to the list of things you don't understand, then. Just calling a function will do nothing to the value of the string in the calling function. `words` *remains the same*.